# Null condition not showing output

Tags: c, function, linked-list, null, segmentation-fault

```
struct node *position(int key)
{
    struct node *p1 = head;
    while (p1->info != key && p1 != NULL)
    {
        p1 = p1->link;
    }
    if (p1 == NULL)
        printf("Insertion not possible");
    return p1;
}

insertafter(int item)
{
    struct node *new = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    struct node *p2 = position(item);
    int ele;
    printf("Enter element to be inserted ");
    scanf("%d", &ele);
    if (p2 == NULL)
        printf("Insertion not possible");
    else
    {
        new->info = ele;
        new->link = p2->link;
        p2->link = new;
    }  
}
```

So everything else is working fine except when I do the null condition check. It inserts correctly after the required element and all but if I give an element which is not present in the linked list it should be returning insertion not possible as the element is not found (null condition) but instead it is displaying segmentation fault.

Comment: Just as a side note: `scanf` scans *user input* – and this one always might be invalid, and `scanf` might fail in consequence! Thus check its return value. If you do so, only create a new node after scanning so you don't create one in vain, if the case might be.

Comment: Can you add the context? There are some declarations missing, like `node`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

segmentation fault is due to the order of conditions in the while loop of the position function. You are first checking `p1->info != key` and then checking `p1 != NULL`. If `p1` is `NULL` trying to access `p1->info` will result in a segmentation fault.To fix this, you should first check if `p1` is `NULL` before trying to access its members.

```
struct node* position(int key)
{
    struct node *p1 = head;
    while(p1 != NULL && p1->info != key)
    {
        p1 = p1->link;
    }
    if(p1 == NULL)
        printf("Insertion not possible\n");
    return p1;
}
```

Comment: segmentation fault is coming when i enter an element which is not thgere in the list .It should be printing insertion not possible when i do that.